# Using arguments in python - value error

Tags: python

I am new to python programming and I tried this code:

```
from sys import argv


script, first, second, third = argv
print "this script is called:" ,script

print "the first variable is called : " ,first

print "the second variable is called : ", second

print "the third variable is called : " ,third
```

I am getting the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/richavarma/Documents/first.py", line 4, in <module>
    script, first, second, third = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

My output should be as follows:

```
this script is called: abc.py
the first variable is called: first
the second variable is called : second
the third variable is called : third
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are executing the script?

Comment: Write out your variables on their own line. Also, if you reference a variable you won't get the variable's name. If you wanted to reference `first` and have it print `first`, you would need to do `first = "first"`.

Comment: Your program works on my end: `python untitled.py 1 2 3
this script is called: untitled.py
the first variable is called :  1
the second variable is called :  2
the third variable is called :  3
`

Comment: My guess is that the error means you're not passing in any command line arguments. If I were you I would add a guard to check the number of arguments passed in to exit gracefully. Could you show us how you're executing your script?

Comment: @rth , I am using IDLE to run these lines. please refer : http://prntscr.com/fa9a82

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal I am using IDLE , post writing the script , I am clicking on RUN .   Please refer prntscr.com/fa9a82

Comment: @Richa that's the problem alright. `sys.argv` expects command line options. You can't do that from IDLE. Try running it from shell with command line args (like in rth's example)

Comment: If you're running it from IDLE, where do you expect the arguments to come from?

Comment: I tried running using Terminal too , yet the same error @ada

Comment: I tried running using Terminal too , yet the same error @AdamSmith 

I have no clue what wrong am I doing. I tried using shell too : http://prntscr.com/fa9gtt

Comment: Please post your terminal command line which return an error. Again on my side everything works.

Comment: If you type `python abc.py first second third` does everything work as expected?

Comment: however, the script does not print which mentions the file name @fileyfood500 , even if I type python abc.py script first second third , it gives an error File "new1.py", line 4, in <module>
    script, first, second, third = argv
ValueError: too many values to unpack

what if I wish to print script , first, second and third?

Comment: abc.py is the first argument, so if you type `python abc.py script first second third` you are giving 5 arguments (abc.py, script, first, second, and third). But you are only assigning 4 of them :/

Comment: got it @fileyfood500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, argv takes arguments from the command line. If you type this command into the command line:

```
python test.py first second third
```

You will pass 4 arguments to your python code: test.py, first, second, and third
You can take in all 4 arguments as inputs by assignment like so:

```
from sys import argv

(filename, arg1, arg2, arg3) = argv
```

After this you can use any of the arguments as strings with their variable names.